# How do I read the variables of TextGrid file into Python?

Tags: python, text

The transcriptions of the COSINE language corpus look as follows:

```
File type = "ooTextFile"
Object class = "TextGrid"

xmin = 0 
xmax = 3931.56874994773
tiers? <exists> 
size = 8
item []:
    item [1]:
        class = "IntervalTier"
        name = "Phrases"
        xmin = 0
        xmax = 3931.56874994773
        intervals: size = 1938
        intervals [1]:
            xmin = 0
            xmax = 3.59246613841739
            text = "Good morning"
        intervals [2]:
            xmin = 3.59246613841739
            xmax = 3.77632771424237
            text = "the dog likes me"
        intervals [3]:
            xmin = 3.77632771424237
            xmax = 8.15464058223137
            text = "fish swim"
        intervals [4]:
            xmin = 8.15464058223137
            xmax = 8.53678424963039
            text = "Sure."
        intervals [5]:
            xmin = 8.53678424963039
            xmax = 9.54622035219737
            text = "Just keep swimming"
```

The files are in .TextGrid format. How could one go ahead to extract the variables `xmin`, `xmax` and `text` for each of the intervals?

EDIT:

The file type can be treated as a normal text file and read line by line. Which was my solution to the problem. It would still be interesting to know if there is a special way to extract information from these type of files. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python Or you can use regex. Give it a try and update the question with your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with textGrid files before see if [this](https://github.com/hbuschme/TextGridTools) helps you. If it doesn't its very easy to write you own function to dot this. looking at textGrid file and the sample file [here](http://www.uni-regensburg.de/sprache-literatur-kultur/sprache-literatur-kultur/allgemeine-vergleichende-sprachwissenschaft/medien/pdfs/summerschool/04_textgrid_example.pdf) it appers there is a set format for these files.

• line 1 and 2 -> file information

• line 3 - > blank, a separator

• line 4 - 7 -> some other information

also line 7 indicates the size, or the number of items in your file.

We can reconstruct these data into a variable as the following:

[image]

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887996/mixing-list-and-dict-in-python) for more about combining dictionaries and lists.

I suggest you to do the following:

Read the file [line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555468/how-should-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python). Do as desired to the information in the first 7 lines. At the 8th line create the item array then you can check the presence of 'item[x], class,name,xmin,xmax, intervals: size, intervals' and assign them to the relevant place of the list/dict. See this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) it describes well about data structures if you are not much familiar.

then you can retrieve the values as

```
list[itemNumber]['class ']
```

or

```
list[itemNumber]['intervals'][intervalNumber-1]['xmin'] #index starts from 0
```

so on...

Hope this helps. Please feel free to comment if you need any further help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I went ahead and saved it as a normal text file, manually deleting parts I don't need and it worked out through use of a bunch of for loops :)

Comment: Great. If that is just a one time job that's quicker.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a python script to do it. What I did was

```
with open('file.Textgrid','r') as f:
  data = f.read()
#print data #Use this to view how the code would look like after the program has opened the files
txttext = ''
for lines in data[9:]:  #informations needed begin on the 9th lines
  line = re.sub('\n','',line) #as there's \n at the end of every sentence.
  line = re.sub ('^ *','',line) #To remove any special characters
  linepair = line.split('=')
  if len(linepair) == 2:
    if linepair[0] == 'xmin':
       xmin == linepair[1]
    if linepair[0] == 'xmax':
       xmax == linepair[1]
    if linepair[0] == 'text':
       if linepair[1].strip().startswith('"') and linepair[1].strip().endswith('"'):
         text = linepair[1].strip()[1:-1]
         txttext += text + '\n'
```

And yeah, save the txtext into a txt file by using write() function and youre good.